# PHP pass POST through HTML a tag

Tags: php, html, post

I have the following code:

```
<a class='list-group-item active' href='index.php?galleryId=$gallery[0]&id=gallery'>
                    <h4 class='list-group-item-heading'>$gallery[2]</h4>
                    <p class='list-group-item-text'>$gallery[3]</p>
                </a>
```

I dont want the user to be able to edit the galleryId in the URL because he could get to galleries which are not for him by editing the value in the URL.

This is the URL: http://localhost/bilderDb/php/index.php?galleryId=2&id=gallery

Is it possible to pass POST through the a tag so the user cant see it. Or is there a other solution to this?

Thanks for your Help!

Edit: I think i was unclear. The user can be able to see the galleryId. I dont want him to be able to change it. When it is in a GET variable he could just change it in the URL.

Comment: You should manage access to your galleries, otherwise anybody having a link will access "private" pages

Comment: Users can also edit POST data if they want to.

Answer (score 0):

There are several way to protect gallery from other users

1. You can use slug name(a random string included with gallery_id like: fun-at-school-90i8j3) for gallery instead of using gallery_id, so its hard to know about gallery slug for other user.
2. You can use hidden input fields on gallery page which contain id of your gallery and type.
3. You can encrypt your gallery_id with secure methods.
4. Put server side validations to check permissions to access for gallery which is associated with users and every time you should check gallery id is associated with valid user or not.

Comment: 2. That's visible to the user. 3. Base64 is not encryption! It is not remotely "secure"!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to pass POST through the a tag

Not without rendering the use of `<a>` pointless.

> so the user cant see it.

The user can see data their browser sends in POST requests. It is their browser.

> Or is there a other solution to this?

Authentication. Authorisation.

If a user shouldn't have access to a URL then, if they request it, verify their identity (e.g. make them log in) and respond with a [403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403).